# Event delegate issue for dynamically added element in jquery

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Col</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="" class="check-input" />
        <span class="error-input"></span>
    </td>
    <td><button class="add-input">Click</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.add-input').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td>Col</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="" class="check-input" /><span class="error-input"></span></td><td></td></tr>');
});

$('.check-input').on('change',function(){
    $(this).next().text('Error');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ch2FM/3/

I can't bind event to element that created dynamically. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding event delegation. Event delegation is done with the closest div. Here I have used document but you can use the closest div to use it as event delegation.

Use this:

```
$(document).on('change','.check-input',function(){
    $(this).next().text('Error');
 });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ch2FM/6/)

---

here's the link to understand about the [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Example:

```
// attach a directly bound event
$( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});

// attach a delegated event
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: *"Event delegation is done with the closest div"* - more like "the closest static parent element"... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('change','.check-input',function(){
    $(this).next().text('Error');
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ch2FM/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `on` handler against an ancestor element, for example the `document` element. Then you can specify the exact selector for the element to listen for as the second parameter:

```
$(document).on('change', '.check-input', function () {
    $(this).next().text('Error');
});
```

This basically means: Listen for the `change` event for all `.check-input` elements that are descendants of the `document` element.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ch2FM/5/)