# jCarousel next/prev buttons not working on dynamically generated div elements?

Tags: jquery, html, jcarousel

I have a jCarousel working with data loaded after an ajax call. Loading is all fine but it does not slide with clicks of next/prev buttons.

My js file:

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
    var itemDiv = $('#items');


$('.jcarousel-control-prev')
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        })
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
        })
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

    $('.jcarousel-control-next')
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        })
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
        })
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=1'
        });

    var setup = function(data, element) {

        var html = '<div class="jcarousel-wrapper">'+'<div class="jcarousel" data-jcarousel="true">'+'<ul>';
        //var html = '<ul>';
        var mrpDiv;

        $.each(data, function() {
          mrpDiv = '<div class="mrp-div" style="text-align:center"><span>' + this.itemMRP + '</span></div>';

            html += '<li class="img-box"><a class="img-box" href="' + this.itemURL + '"><img src="' + this.itemImage + '" alt="' + this.itemTitle + '" style="width=100%"></a><div class="variant-div"><a href="' + this.itemURL + '" title="' + this.itemTitle + '"><div class="varnt-title" style="overflow: hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space: nowrap">' + this.itemTitle + '</div></a></div>'+mrpDiv;
        });
        html += '</ul>'+'</div><a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev inactive" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">‹</a><a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">›</a></div>';
        // Append items
        element.html(html);
        // Reload carousel
        element.find('.jcarousel').jcarousel();
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "apiLink",
        success: function (responseData) {
            if(responseData && responseData.similarItems.length > 0){
                setup(responseData.similarItems, itemDiv);
            } 

        },
        error: function (responseData) {

        }
    });

});
})(jQuery);
```

I am trying to push a div through the above code which has the informations and then willing to be showed in  a carousel.

```
<div id="items"></div>
```

Everything is working fine, just the carousel is not working as it should. If I do not add the things dynamically, I get it working fine.

```
<div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
            <div class="jcarousel" id="items" data-jcarousel="true"><ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev inactive" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">‹</a>
            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">›</a>
         </div>
```

Comment: use event delegation method for dynamic element [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019617/event-delegate-issue-for-dynamically-added-element-in-jquery/21019686#21019686)...

Comment: Your `.on()` method use is incorrect — there is no event handler specified: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the potentially problematic code is with your use of the `.on()` method. You have not specified a event that the method should listen to. I suppose you want to listen to the click event — you should do this:

`.on('click', 'jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {`

instead of:

`.on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {`

...because jQuery would have no idea what event originating from the selected element that it should be listening to.

In addition, `jcarouselcontrol` is not a valid selector. Do you mean `.jcarouselcontorl`?

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine except the issue which was pointed out in the first comment. I had to invoke the methods after the elements were loaded, moving the methods inside of `var setup = function(data, element) {` and everything ran fine.