# SlideUp Jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with 'slideUp' from jquery.

After the 'slideDown' I hide the button that has opened up and I show it in another div. 
This should close the open box

HTML

```
  <div class="ciao">
    <div id="cerca"><input type="text" /></div>
      <div id="flip"><a href="#">button</a></div>
         <div id="panel">
           <ul><li>menu 1 </li><li>menu 2 </li><li>menu 3 </li></ul>
         </div>
      </div>
```

JS

```
       $("#flip a").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        $('#flip').animate({top:'30px'});
        $('#cerca').append('<a href="#" id="close">CHIUDI</a>');
     });

    $("#cerca a#close").click(function(){
        $(this).parent('#panel').slideUp("slow");
     });
```

JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/rttoorop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events on dynamically created element. You will also need to modify the selector to target element with id `panel`:

```
$("#cerca").on('click','a#close',function(){
   $(this).parent().siblings('#panel').slideUp("slow");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nzqnz9dn/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the 'click' event to element which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need event delegation method for dynamically created element [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click',"#cerca a#close",function(){
        $(this).parent('#panel').slideUp("slow");
     });
```

[I've answered more about event delegation method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019617/event-delegate-issue-for-dynamically-added-element-in-jquery/21019686#21019686)