# jQuery On click wont fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textbox`, a checkbox and a `span` tag. When I click on the checkbox, it should show its state in the `span` tag.  When `textbox` is updated, it reinserts the checkbox block. When you click on the checkbox now, it fails to update the state.

I am using the `on` event handler for checkbox click event, so I expect it to work.

Any idea why this is not working as expected?

```js
$('div[role] input[type=checkbox]').on('click', chg);

$('div[role] input[type=text]').on('input', sourceChanged);

function chg() {
  var istiki = $(this).is(":checked");
  $('#upd').html(istiki);
}

function sourceChanged() {
  $('span', $(this).closest('.input-group')).html('<input type="checkbox">');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="Tiki" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" /></span>
</div>
<span id="upd"></span>
```

Comment: You are appending a new checkbox over the old one and that makes it a new element that was not in the DOM when you set the handler. This goes to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event delegate issue for dynamically added element in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019617/event-delegate-issue-for-dynamically-added-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Out of curiosity, the `.input-group` already has a checkbox, then why are you doing this - `$('span', $(this).closest('.input-group')).html('<input type="checkbox">');`?

Comment: Would you guys even read the question before littering with comments? I know I am adding new elements. I wrote that. I wrote I used `on` event too. I was just wrong with the syntax. The non-dynamic ancestor is what I was after.

Comment: This is for demo purpose only TJ. I have slightly more complex stuff happening in there.

Comment: Spokey. Thanks for that. I should have seen that earlier.

Comment: I vote this question to be closed as per Spokey's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're dynamically creating a new checkbox when the value changes, you need to delegate the event to your checkbox by assigning it to a non-dynamic ancestor:

```
$('div[role]').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', chg);
```

Note how I've used `change` instead of `click` as this is more appropriate for checkboxes.

---

In the below snippet I've also changed `$(this).is(":checked")` to just `this.checked`.

```js
$('div[role]').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', chg);

$('div[role] input[type=text]').on('input', sourceChanged);

function chg() {
  var istiki = this.checked;
  $('#upd').html(istiki);
}

function sourceChanged() {
  $('span', $(this).closest('.input-group')).html('<input type="checkbox">');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="Tiki" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" /></span>
</div>
<span id="upd"></span>
```

Note also that if you want it to say `false` you should convert your `istiki` variable to a string:

```
$('#upd').html('' + isticki);
```

Comment: You need to... because you're inserting a new checkbox, the original one to which you binded the event is no longer there.

Comment: Thanks James. Din't know I should put dynamic stuff on the right side.