# jQuery on blur / focusout not firing on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically adding an element in jQuery, and upon doing so, I'm focusing on the element. I'm trying to then remove this element on `blur`. However, the `blur` event or the `focusout` event don't seem to be firing when the focus is lost.

**Appending the element:**

```
var searchForm = '<input id="header-search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">';
$('body').append(searchForm);
$('#header-search').focus();
```

**Binding to the `blur()` event:**

```
$('#header-search').on('blur', function() {
    alert('blur');      
    $(this).remove();       
});
```

**EDIT:**
I just created a jsFiddle, and it seems to function as I want. Strange.
https://jsfiddle.net/danhaswings/cpczLL7g/

Comment: use: [event delegation method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019617/event-delegate-issue-for-dynamically-added-element-in-jquery/21019686#21019686)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
$(document).on('blur', '#header-search', function() {
    alert('blur');      
    $(this).remove();       
});
```

Since your element is being added dynamically and when your code is executed, no DOM element is found with selector `#header-search`. So, you need to change the code like above to fix for dynamically added elements.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I understand why this wasn't working now.

Answer (score 3):

If your element is appended before adding your event, you need to bind the event to a parent that already exists using `$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );`.

This is [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and you have to use .on() using delegated-events approach

```js
$(document).on('blur', '#header-search', function() {
  alert('blur');
  if ($(this).val() == '' && $searchButton.is(':active') == false) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});

var searchForm = '<input id="header-search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search STRI...">';
$('body').append(searchForm);
$('#header-search').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

When trying to bind an event to any 'Dynamically added element', it'd be better to write

```
$(document.body).on("blur", "#header-search", function () {
   // do anything you wanna do...
   alert("blur");
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `$searchButton.is(':active')` on line 7, the var was not defined.

in this fork is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/w5jpypcy/

Answer (score 0):

In your code you must have added Jquery first and then the HTML like

```
$('#header-search').on('blur', function() {
alert('blur');
if ($(this).val() == '' && $searchButton.is(':active') == false) {
    $(this).remove();
}
});


var searchForm = '<input id="header-search" type="text" class="form-control"     placeholder="Search STRI...">';
$('body').append(searchForm);
$('#header-search').focus();
```

that is why it is working in your JSFiddle where you have added Blur event after you created your runtime input tag and not in your environment.

Hope this helps.